# How can I show data related to a max value from a dataset with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe where I have more than one column and I want to know additional data to the maximum value of one column

For example, given the following code, show the country where the number is the highest per year per causes What I did was:

```
var=data.groupby(["Year","Causes"])["number"].max()
```

But this only shows the max value for each of the years and each of the causes. **I would like to know which country is the one associated with the max value from the number.**

---

1. This code shows the highest number per cause per year, but I need to
   show the country associated with the highest number per cause per
   year

---

I tried using idxmax() instead of max() but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way but if I've understood what you'd like to achieve and your data structure then this works:

```
var=data.groupby(["Year","Causes"])["number"].max()
var = pd.DataFrame(var)
new = var.merge(data, how='inner').drop_duplicates()
new
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var=data.groupby(["Year","Causes"])["number"].max()
print(df[var]);
```